# Java. Вопрос по архитектуре сервера для игры

Tags: java, сокет, tcp-ip, io

Думаю над архитектурой сервера для игры и встал вопрос над тем, как обрабатывать подключения клиентов. Протокол - **tcp/ip**.

Стоит выбор между **многопоточной архитектурой** (1 клиент - 1 поток) и **асинхронным вводом/выводом** (когда чтение не блокирует поток, если данных нет, а возвращает 0 и поток может обрабатывать других клиентов, то есть 1 поток - много клиентов).

Игра - mmorpg, где потенциально люди могут стоять в городе и не передавать почти никакого ввода на сервер, но так же бывают динамичные моменты где важен быстрый ответ сервера.

---

*Потоки при остановке **не используют CPU циклы**, **более отзывчивые**, однако **держат оперативную память**, чего бы не хотелось в слабоактивных местах, где от игроков почти не идет ввода.*

---

*Асинхронный подход использует **меньше памяти**, **менее уязвим к слабоактивным клиентам**, **но менее эффективен для активных клиентов.***

Выбор очень сложный, поэтому хотел бы спросить совета у более опытных, которые имели опыт с данными подходами, спасибо.

Comment: Одно из двух просто не масштабируется и жрет абсолютно лишние ресурсы. Другое стоит брать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил динамический пулл потоков. Плюсы от него ты знаешь. А размер этого пулла можно изменять в зависимости от нагрузки, чем и сэкономишь на CPU, и достигнешь достаточного быстродействия в зависимости от нужды пользователей

Comment: да, примерно к такому выводу и сам пришел (очень долго не было ответа, даже не думал, что будет), но +1 ставлю, чтобы другим был ответ)